# XML Canonicalization lexicographical ordering

Tags: xml, canonicalization

There are official test cases for XML canonicalization which can be found here: [Test cases for Canonical XML 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n2-testcases.)

One of them looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE doc [<!ATTLIST e9 attr CDATA "default">]>
<doc>
   <e1   />
   <e2   ></e2>
   <e3   name = "elem3"   id="elem3"   />
   <e4   name="elem4"   id="elem4"   ></e4>
   <e5 a:attr="out" b:attr="sorted" attr2="all" attr="I'm"
      xmlns:b="http://www.ietf.org"
      xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org"
      xmlns="http://example.org"/>
   <e6 xmlns="" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org">
      <e7 xmlns="http://www.ietf.org">
         <e8 xmlns="" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org">
            <e9 xmlns="" xmlns:a="http://www.ietf.org"/>
         </e8>
      </e7>
   </e6>
</doc>
```

The given canonicalized form is

```
<doc>
   <e1></e1>
   <e2></e2>
   <e3 id="elem3" name="elem3"></e3>
   <e4 id="elem4" name="elem4"></e4>
   <e5 xmlns="http://example.org" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org" xmlns:b="http://www.ietf.org" attr="I'm" attr2="all" b:attr="sorted" a:attr="out"></e5>
   <e6>
      <e7 xmlns="http://www.ietf.org">
         <e8 xmlns="">
            <e9 attr="default"></e9>
         </e8>
      </e7>
   </e6>
</doc>
```

I'm wondering why `b:attr="sorted"` comes before `a:attr="out"` in the sorted output... I'd be really thankful if someone could clarify this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't look at the namespace prefixes; look at the namespace URIs.

Although `a` comes before `b`, `i` comes before `w`:

```
  xmlns:b="http://www.ietf.org"
  xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org"
```

Therefore `b:attr="sorted"` comes before `a:attr="out"` canonically.

This is explained in [section 2.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n2-testcases/#sec-Example-SETags):

> **Note**: In `e5`, `b:attr` precedes `a:attr` because the primary key is namespace URI not namespace prefix